# TextBox B in Form2 to display text from TextBox A in Form 1 using C# and WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

After entering in the appropriate text and pressing enter, I want txtbA text in Form1 to display in txtbB in Form 2.

I already have the key events code written, but I can't seem to figure out the rest.

Visual basic seems to be more straightforward with this, and I am new to C#.

This is using WinForms.

I am really only familiar with visual basic's way of handling this:

```
txtbA.text = My.Forms.Form2.txbB.text
```

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: Post what you have already tried till now

Comment: Basically, all I am familiar with is visual basic:

txtbA.text = My.Forms.Form2.txtbB.text

Comment: It appears c# uses something different from My.Forms

Comment: There is similar to `vb.net` concept - [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx).

Comment: At the point when Enter is pressed in Form1, is Form2 already open?...or are you to open a new instance (each time?) and pass the value?  At any rate, keep the reference to Form2 at class level in Form1 so you can re-use it when needed.

Comment: Right, Form1 will open an instance of Form2 upon pressing the Enter key.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a static variable

In Form1

```
public static string txtbAtext 
{
    get { return txtbAtext ; }
    set {txtbAtext  = value; }
}
```

OnTextChanged Event

```
txtAtext = txtA.Text;
```

In Form2

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
txtbB.Text = Form1.txtAText;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest and not very elegant way is to do ist like this:

Make a property in the second form, that can hold a Textbox and set the Text property in the TextChange event of the property in Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public TextBox TextBoxWithSameText { get; set; }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBoxWithSameText != null)
            TextBoxWithSameText.Text = textBox2.Text;
    }
}
```

All you have to do now is to set the property to the Form1.textbox1 when the second form (Form2) is created:

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.TextBoxWithSameText = textbox1;
```

Comment: Do you think I would be able to do something like this instead?  Sorry, I don't think this is formatting the code correctly...

    private void txtbClassNameA_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
               
                txtbClassNameA.Text = frm2.txtbClassPageA.Text;
            }
       
        }

Comment: You should not create the second form in the event handler of the first text box. If you want to have both forms standing side by side you have to create the second form in the constructor of the first form.

Comment: Okey doke, I will give this a try.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to exchange strings between two Forms classes, you can use a third class. Once added to your project, you need to instantiate this new Class1 in your Form1 and Form2:

```
Class1 class = new Class1;
```

Make sure Class1 has a constructor. Now, you can create properties in your Class1, with get and set properties:

```
public string TextA
{
    get
    {
        return textA;
    }

    set
    {
       textA = value;
    }
}
```

You can then call these properties from any other class that has instantiated your Class1, like so:

```
class.TextA = txtbA.Text;
```

In order to show the text in the other textbox, you need an event to trigger changing the txtbB.Text value. You could use txtbA.ValueChanged event, or a button with a Click event. You should figure out what event is most appropriate for your project.

I hope this helped! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> Right, Form1 will open an instance of Form2 upon pressing the Enter
>   key. Thanks!

You can setup Form2 to receive the initial value for the TextBox via its Constructor:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(string InitialValue)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.txtbB.Text = InitialValue;
    }
}
```

Then in Form1 you'd do something like:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(this.txtbA.Text);
f2.Show();
```

Comment: Ok, great - these are the steps I am sort of taking a look at for the first time.  Thank you.